# allocate a new memory for matrix of objects

Tags: c++, object, memory-management, matrix

I have the class `Cars` and the object (pointer to pointers of digits):

```
Cars** arr;
```

I want to allocate a new memory, how can I do it?

something like:

```
arr = new Cars*[1]; // make one row
arr[0] = new Cars[10]; // make 10 cols

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr[0][i] = d; // d is a parameter of: Digits d;
}
```

I set rows = 1 because I think there is always 1 row.

please help me cause I think I miss something..

Comment: Yup, that seems correct enough. Though...is 'Digits' a subclass of 'Cars'? If not, it won't work.

Comment: Use 'vector' instead... so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = new Cars*[1]; // make one row
arr[0] = new Cars[10]; // make 10 cols
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   arr[0][i] = d; // d must be an object of Cars
}
```

since `arr` stores elements of `Cars` type, `d` must be an `object` of `Cars` or can be converted to/viewed as object of `Cars`.

You'd better to use vector of vectors instead, which is easier to use and you don't need to bother with the memory management issue with dynamic arrays.

Comment: Why do you need to rename the array? I fail to see the reason for that, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ATaylor I did not rename it, because OP used new_arr and arr at different places, I changed them to use the same name. UPDATE: It seems that OP updated the post, so I removed those part that changing names.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't see the original version, so that's why I was a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to std::vector instead

```
std::vector<std::vector<Cars>> arr;
arr.resize(1); // make one row
arr[0].resize(10); // make 10 cols

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr[0][i] = d; // d is a parameter of: Digits d;
}
```

Note: d must be a Car.